# ASP.NET /MVC C# advanced login with Unique HD serial number

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to implement advanced login mechanism in my ASP.NET MVC web site that is: users should be logged in with username and password only from one machine (the one that was used when the first time registered and logged in the application).

I was thinking about getting the client Hard Drive serial number ? Is this possible?
If not, can someone suggest me a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Igor

Comment: I wouldn't call that "advanced", i'd call that "primitive".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access unique PC identifiers, other than your browser. Check [panopticlick browser uniqueness research](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Aside from that, I don't get the requirement to limit website access to the first used machine. It is not uncommon to used different devices these days (desktop, laptop, tablet, phone)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible, limiting your user to only using the machine they first logged in with would be a really bad design decision. What happens if their computer fails, and they need to get a new one, or replace some hardware? Remember when Microsoft Office used to make you re-activate every time you made a change to your computer's hardware? No one wants that. Aside from that, users use a wide variety of devices... a desktop at home, a laptop at a cafe, an iPhone on the road.

Using javascript, it is more or less possible to uniquely identify a browser, but that still would be subject to change, and the eventual locking out of legitimate users.

If you want to make sure a user is looged in on one device at a **time** that's a much more reasonable requirement. All you'd have to do in that case (I'm over simplifying a bit) is maintain a table of currently logged in users, and then reject subsequent login attempts for that user if they're already logged in.